# Getting a row index from a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity) it was mentioned that an overload of the `Select` method can be used to reference an index value. This would be exactly what I need to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093663/how-to-query-every-n-th-value-from-an-ordered-set-of-entities)

However, when I try to use this overload as below, I get a `NotSupportedException`.

```
DbObjects.OrderBy (o => o.CreatedOn ).Select((o,i) => new {entity = o, rownumber = i})
```

Is this indexed overload supported by LINQ to Entities? Am I missing something in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ralph, I did update [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity/1165249#1165249) to fix the exception. It will work fine for [him](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165028/how-do-i-add-row-number-to-a-linq-query-or-entity), but since it's client-side it's not what you need for [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093663/how-to-query-every-n-th-value-from-an-ordered-set-of-entities). No, L2E does not support this overload. I'll answer your other question over there.